# How to load the colored text dynamically and fade out in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display some text with red background color and white font color in top center of screen. and That should fade away after 6 seconds. any idea how to do it in jquery

Comment: In response to what action, or event? What've you tried? What mark-up are you using? Have you tried anything so far, what went wrong..? Where's the dynamic text coming from?

Comment: The text will be the responseText coming after successful ajax complete its request. i am confused how to start. i want something like message appeared on top of gmail when we do some things. it will be like `data updated and so`. i just want to know the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this fiddle can help

http://jsfiddle.net/ASRKR/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeout effect in JQuery, just set duration time in params. http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

ps but remember you set time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of background too, you should include [this .js file](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) in your page too.